# Which SQL engine atop Hadoop?

Tags: open-source, java, database, sql, hadoop

Since [Hadoop](https://hive.apache.org) came out, there have been various commercial and/or open-source attempts to expose some compatibility with [SQL](http://drill.apache.org).

I am seeking one which is good for low-latency querying, and supports the most common [CRUD](https://spark.apache.org), including [the basics!] along these lines: `CREATE TABLE`, `INSERT INTO`, `SELECT * FROM`, `UPDATE Table SET C1=2 WHERE`, `DELETE FROM`, and `DROP TABLE`.

I will be utilising them from Python, however there does seem to be a [Python JDBC wrapper](https://spark.apache.org/sql). Additionally it needs to be scalable for big and small data (starting on a single-node "cluster").

Here is what I've found thus far:

- [Apache Hive](https://hive.apache.org) (SQL-like, with interactive SQL thanks to the Stinger initiative)
- [Apache Drill](http://drill.apache.org) (ANSI SQL support)
- [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org) ([Spark SQL](https://spark.apache.org/sql), queries only, add data via Hive, [RDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD) or [Paraquet](http://parquet.io/))
- [Apache Phoenix](http://phoenix.apache.org) (built atop [Apache HBase](http://hbase.apache.org), lacks full [transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) support, [relational operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_operators) and some built-in functions)
- [Presto](https://github.com/facebook/presto) from Facebook (can query Hive, [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org), relational DBs &etc. Doesn't seem to be designed for low-latency responses across small clusters, or support `UPDATE` operations. It is optimized for data warehousing or analytics[¹](http://prestodb.io/docs/current/overview/use-cases.html))
- [SQL-Hadoop](https://www.mapr.com/why-hadoop/sql-hadoop) via [MapR community edition](https://www.mapr.com/products/hadoop-download) (seems to be a packaging of Hive, [HP Vertica](http://www.vertica.com/hp-vertica-products/sqlonhadoop), SparkSQL, Drill and a [native ODBC wrapper](http://package.mapr.com/tools/MapR-ODBC/MapR_ODBC))
- [Apache Kylin](http://www.kylin.io) from Ebay (provides an SQL interface and multi-dimensional analysis [[OLAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP)], "… offers ANSI SQL on Hadoop and supports most ANSI SQL query functions". It depends on HDFS, MapReduce, Hive and HBase; and seems targeted at very large data-sets though maintains low query latency)
- [Apache Tajo](http://tajo.apache.org) (ANSI/ISO SQL standard compliance with [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC) driver support [[benchmarks against Hive and Impala](http://blogs.gartner.com/nick-heudecker/apache-tajo-enters-the-sql-on-hadoop-space)])
- [Cascading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_(software))'s [Lingual](http://docs.cascading.org/lingual/1.0/)[²](http://docs.cascading.org/lingual/1.0/#sql-support) ("Lingual provides JDBC Drivers, a SQL command shell, and a catalog manager for publishing files [or any resource] as schemas and tables.")

Which—from this list or elsewhere—would you recommend, and why?